# What is this veggie sushi in japan?

Tags: sushi

I found this photo on the internet. I am going to japan next week. I would like to know what is the veggie on the sushi. I think it looks like some spring onion but would like to be sure.

[image]

Comment: Can't say for sure, but it looks like spring onion… however, it doesn't look like actual Japanese sushi, it looks a bit "LA nouveau" to me. Are you certain it's actually Japanese?

Comment: Not really sure but the site mention Yoshi Zushi in Ueno, Tokyo.

Comment: Can't be totally sure but it looks more like chives to me.

Comment: tbh, it's nearly 20 years since I was there… I guess there's such a thing as 're-importing' LA ideas back to Japan ;) @Cindy chives are 'green all the way', spring onions go to white, but I'm not sure; you may be right. [stupid long google images link](https://www.google.com/search?q=chives+vs+spring+onions&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ACYBGNT1I3fhJ5hcvkLoB0f7oXIHdJ9ZQg:1568569887763&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=EBWgLl62A3Ps_M%253A%252C0BTEZafCyM16fM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTSPwrfUWDXxKaC2rf3qYpcIPhJeA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiordyXstPkAhWzmFwKHWy6BOsQ9QEwAHoECAIQAw#imgrc=EBWgLl62A3Ps_M:)

Comment: @Tetsujin Looking at the pics you linked, I'm thinking maybe Asian chives?

Comment: @Cindy - I'd had that thought too - but still can't be 100% certain

Comment: Incidentally - Japan is really good at showing you pictures of everything you're about to order [& even stunningly realistic plastic models in some places] - you could maybe reverse that onto the serving staff & show them that picture. There's every possibility they will recognise it immediately.

Comment: @Tetsujin Guess we can't know for sure. Perhaps the OP can update us after his trip.

Comment: Looks like Chinese Chives to me.

Comment: That is Scallion Sushi ;-)

Comment: Looks like nira (don't know the english name of that)

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allium_tuberosum)? The entry gives “Nira” as Japanese name.

Comment: @Stephie, yeah, looks a little bit like it ^^'

Answer (score 1):

It's [scallion sushi](https://www.flickr.com/photos/44616490@N04/9122943475/)

And [again](https://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g1066451-d3610615-i87605081-Sushi_Bar_Yasuda-Minato_Tokyo_Tokyo_Prefecture_Kanto.html)

"Filler text to reach the 30 character limit for posts."

Comment: Welcome! Instead of a “filler”, the answer would benefit from a bit more information... and as both links essential lead to one source, it definitely needs more details and explanation to avoid a “spammy” touch.

Comment: @Stephie, I really don't have anything positive to say about scallion sushi, so I thought it would be better to leave it at that. I linked two separate sources with different takes on the dish.